# styled-components: using `& + &` selector and adapt based on props

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have some components rendered with the same styled-component, and I want to make some margin-top between them

```
const Item = styled.div`
  color: ${props => props.active ? 'red' : '#333'};
  & + & {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
`

<Item active={false}/>
<Item active={false}/>
<Item active={false}/>
```

so far so good,

but when one of them has a `true` active prop, the margin-top is missing, I found that is because `<Item active={false}/>` and `<Item active={true} />` do not have the same class name.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

P.S.

I'm just get started with styled-components, and I'm also looking for best practice with it.

Comment: I'm just curious - what is the `& + &` meaning?

Comment: It meas `${Item} + ${Item}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the components should have the same class name as they are using the same `styled-components` component.

But regarding the `& + &`, if you want all of them, then just plain `margin-top: 10px` is enough, if you want to do on in between, you can just specify the `first-child, last-child` to be `margin: 0`.

```js
<React.Fragment>
  <Item active={false}>First</Item>
  <Item active={false}>Second</Item>
  <Item active={false}>Third</Item>
</React.Fragment>
```

A codesandbox for demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/62l02knn5r